# Embed non-square Youtube video as square

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, embedding

I want to embed a non-square Youtube video as a square in my website.

Setting `width=""` and `height=""` on the iframe works to  make the player square. However, the video inside the is not square: there are black bars at the top and bottom.

Is there any way to make the player 'zoom in' and play the video as square?

```
<iframe width="200" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8nt3edWLgIg?autoplay=0&playsinline=1&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

PS: embedding doesn't seem to work in stackoverflow snippets, so here's a jsbin link:
https://jsbin.com/felosadewi/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to get a pure css solution to your show the video clipped to fit in a 1:1 box.

https://jsbin.com/woralocoti/edit?html,output

I have dont it by putting the video in a fixed aspect box (16:9) using `padding-bottom:56%;` (16/9).

And then centering that box in a 1:1 box with `overflow:hidden;`